# How can I modularize this application? Can you give me a code level simple example?

Tags: php, facebook

My application has a single index.php

Main things it does are

1.  Uses facebook login to let the user login to my application.  (In future I will use additional sites like google etc for login etc)

2.  Does the "Main work"

3.  Displays the result.

Main work:

1.  Gets an access token from fb. - Takes <10 ms

2.  Gets data set 1 - Uses accesstoken and gets data about the user. - Takes about a second.

3.  Gets data set 2 - Spiders each of the friend in the list for partiuclar information - Takes about a second for each friend.  So, takes around 300 seconds on average.

4.  Does some processing - Few Seconds

Problem Areas
1.  Step 3 exceeds Max_Execution_Time always.

Solution constraints
1.  Wish to stick with php only.  No Python/ruby.

My code skeleton is :

```
<?php

//  Login
$facebook->getloginurl ......

//Main work
$access_token = $facebook-> ...... 
$user_id = $facebok->get ......

// Following is the time consuming step
foreach $friend_of_that_user .... get information required for this app.

//Displays result
echo ""
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a single request for each friend! this can be enhanced by one of the following methods:

1. [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/):
   Getting the name and 5 movies of the first 100 friends:

   ```
   me?fields=friends.limit(100).fields(name,movies.limit(5).fields(name))
   ```
2. [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/):
   For example, to get the details of 5 of your friends, you can issue the following Batch request:

   ```
   curl \
      -F 'access_token=...' \
      -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-friends","relative_url":"me/friends?limit=5",},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}"}]' \
      https://graph.facebook.com/
   ```

Now I would really recommend considering pagination instead of removing the `limit` field all together. If pagination is relevant to your app, it could enhance the experience A LOT!

Comment: The example really helped- me?fields=friends.limit(100).fields(name,movies.limit(5).fields(name))

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` loop is the problem. You're making a separate API call for each friend. That takes forever and isn't needed. That many API calls will also get your app blocked pretty quickly.

Once you have the user authenticated, you can make a call to `$facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,...', 'GET');` to get all the data you need in one call. On a bad day, that should take <5 sec. With [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) you can dive deep into your friends' data, as long as you have the right permissions.

If you have a user with a very large number of friends, Facebook may paginate the results. Even with that, you should have everything you need in no more than 10 API calls.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that I can get all the data using $facebook->api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,...', 'GET');   Will check out more in fb.  Thanks for this pointer.